# How to create new file html in angular8

Tags: angular, components

I created a new file in `src/app/app.component.html`. And when i run `ng serve -o`
I don't see the content in my `app.componet.html` template, but instead in Chrome I see the string "./app.component.html". Here's the contents of my component itself:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `./app.component.html`,
  styles: [
    '.isActive { text-decoration: underline; }',
    '.oddCategory { color: green }'
  ]
})
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Use ````templateUrl```` instead of ````template````

Comment: thx now its working

Comment: Reworded to make the question more clear and actionable.

Comment: thx , i will try better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

template: './app.component.html',
replace ` to '